# How to create a text box using PGF

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I'm styling my beamer presentation using PGF picture and I want to add a textbox with a specific width.

The following line doesn't provide a width parameter.

```
\pgftext[at=\pgfpoint{.05\paperwidth}{-.3\paperheight},left,base]{\inserttitle}
```

**Note:** I strictly want to use PGF. Tikz is not an option.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Why shouldn't TikZ be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also don't see why TikZ is not an option, but if you insist on that: How about using a minipage within a pgfnodebox? E.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}

\begin{document}

\begin{pgfpicture}{0cm}{0cm}{3cm}{3cm}
% (0cm,0cm) is the lower left corner,
% (3cm,3cm) is the upper right corner.
\pgfnodebox{box1}[stroke]{\pgfxy(1,1)}{\begin{minipage}{1cm}This is a long text which should only take a width of 1cm.\end{minipage}}{2pt}{2pt}
\end{pgfpicture}

\end{document}
```

You can then use whatever alignment you want within the minipage.

Answer (score 2):

If `TiKZ` instead of `pgf` is a valid option, something like

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\title{This is  a long title for my presentation}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\tikz \node[draw, fill=red!30, text width=5cm, align=left] at (0.05\paperwidth,-.3\paperheight) {\inserttitle};
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

Comment: No, I strictly want pgf directives.

Comment: @AryaMz Hi and welcome, please add your wish explicitely to the question.

Comment: @AryaMz Then could you better explain where and how do you want to use this command? Providing a complete minimal working (or not) example is also suggested. From `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` including all relevant (and only relevant) packages.